# Does the synthesis method used to make graphene oxide composites matter?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm doing a research project to test the photothermal conversion performance of graphene oxide composite materials.

We're using a number of different metals and metal oxides ($\ce{Au}$, $\ce{Ag}$, $\ce{Cu}$, $\ce{TiO2}$, $\ce{SnO2}$, etc.) and for each material the literature suggests different methods of synthesis.

We are only using chemical methods; the ones suggested include microwave-assisted reduction, redox reactions, and hydrolysis. Will using different methods of synthesis for each compound have an effect on the outcome of the experiment? Should the same (or similar) method be used for all of the composites?